# Domain models and the List / Detail page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I need some advice on the a question I have been battling with on DDD .

I have a  domain model which is a aggregate root

```
public class  Objective {
   public int ObjectiveId { get; private set; }

        public string ObjectiveDescription { get; private set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }

        public DateTime TargetDate { get; private set; }

        public DateTime? CompletedDate { get; private set; }

        public int EmploymentId { get; private set; }

        public List<Skill> RelatedSkills { get; private set; }

        public List<Goal> RelatedGoals { get; private set; }
       // few more properties.
}
```

I have 2 views one is a List View and another is a details View.

The List View has a IEnumerable  which has just 3 fields

```
class ObjectiveListVM{
   public int ObjectiveId { get; private set; }

            public string ObjectiveDescription { get; private set; }

            public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
}
```

The Details view has a ObjectiveDetailViewModel  which has 90 percent of the fields from the Objective domain model plus a few more.

I have a repository which gets me either a list or one objective

```
IObjectiveRepo
{
   Objective GetById();
   IEnumerable<Objective> GetList();
}
```

This is how I have implemented DDD and Repository pattern. 
My question is this , my GetList query is really expensive , it only needs data from 3 columns but since my Repositories should always return domain objects , I End up returning a list the entire Objective domain object which has child lists and lots of fields.

The solution I thought of is to have another ObjectiveSummary domain model which just has a few fields and is returned by the GetList repo method. But it then breaks some other principles of DDD mainly that ObjectiveSummary is a Anemic Domain model . In fact its not really a model , its more of a DTO in my head.

This is such a common scenario that I feel I am missing something very basic in my implementation or interpretation of DDD / repository patterns .

Can some of the experts point out the mistake i have made in the implementation  or highlight a way to address this problem without expensive queries ?

Note : I can thinka few ways of getting around this problem.But I am more interested in finding the correct way which does not break the principles of the architecture/pattern that I am using.

Comment: Have you investigated or considered making the navigation properties on `Objective` lazy-loaded by default?

Comment: Word of advice - pragmatism beats dogma in 98% of the cases. Do not fear having anemic aspects of your model.

Comment: @stephen.vakil : Wouldnt  the lazy load just moves the problem in a different place, ie instead of causing performance issues on the list , it will cause performance issues on the details view. The kind of queries my ORM will issue depending on the lazy loaded properties I access will vary and tend to be more than 1 which is equally problematic

Comment: @Pratik you would have to be explicit with `.Include()` when you know in advance that you want the children of `Objective` to be loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not query your domain model. An aggregate is always loaded in its entirety so it does not lend itself well to querying.

As soon as you think about lazy-loading you are probably not using an optimal approach. Lazy-loading is evil. Don't do it :)

What you are after is a *query layer* of sorts. This is directly related to CQRS. The query side *only* returns data. It has no behaviour and you return the most basic structure that you can. In the C# world that I am also in I use a `DataRow` or `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.  If it is really complex I may opt for a DTO:

```
public interface IObjectiveQuery
{
    DataRow ForList(int id);
    bool Contains(string someUniqueKey);

    IEnumerable<DataRow> Search(string descriptionLike, DateTime startDate);

    string Description(int id);
}
```

Give it a go.  I think you'll find it simplifies things immensely.  Your domain should only be concerned about the *command*/*write* side of things.

Comment: so what you are essentially suggesting is that the query side does not need to have a Domain Object / Aggregate approach at all  ?  It just uses either the ORM objects or the DTO's ?  Any example projects / articles which give details of this ?

Comment: That is correct.  The query side goes to the data store and uses the simplest representation that will do.  I have a simple example in my [service bus samples](https://github.com/Shuttle/shuttle-esb-samples).  Have a look at the `ProcessManagement` solution.  The `Shuttle.Process.QueryServer` project builds up the query side and the data access is defined in the `Shuttle.ProcessManagement` project.  Hope that helps :)

Comment: I fully agree. The query side can be separated. It allows you to specialize your SQL queries (please don't use an ORM here).

Comment: I haven't explicitly mentioned not to use on ORM on the read side so I definitely agree with jgauffin on that.  I tend to use a very thin abstraction over ADO.NET so it is as close to plain ADO.NET without any duplication of code.  Many queries are written in plain SQL also.

Comment: @jgauffin and Eben  is there a way to avoid creating another set of classes which are query classes  and have a generic way of getting results ? I have to create a view model a query class for each query Eg 2 sets of classes(VM and Query) for objeciveforEmployeeQuery and another 2 for ObjectiveForDateRangeQuery  for the example in the question. This is apart from the actual Objective class  . Seems like a lot of clutter

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the results you may not need a class.  Could you not return a `DataRow`?  You could also return a `dynamic` object in some instances.  I have used the `dynamic` to return objects from a web-api, e.g.: `return new { Id = IdColumn.MapFrom(row), Name = NameColumn.MapFrom(row) };`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with it is to return `IQueryable<Objective>` from your repository instead of `IEnumerable<Objective>`.

```
public interface IObjectiveRepository
{
   Objective GetById();
    IQueryable<Objective> GetList();
}
```

It will allow you to keep the repository simple and add more logic to the queries in application/domain layer without performance loss. The following query will be executed on the db server, including the projection to `ObjectiveListVM`:

```
public IReadOnlyList<ObjectiveListVM> GetSummaryList()
{
    return _repository
        .GetList()
        .Select(o => new ObjectiveListVM
        {
            ObjectiveId = o.ObjectiveId,
            ObjectiveDescription = o.ObjectiveDescription,
            StartDate = o.StartDate
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

You can use Automapper's [Queryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) to make the projection to VMs easier.

```
return _repository
    .GetList()
    .ProjectTo<ObjectiveListVM>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I have played with the idea of IQueryable but has more issues than benefits in my opinion. My repositories get used by a lot of other people in the team and in many different ways ( Web APP / Desktop App ) 

I have had too many issues with people missing the ToList() and ending up either with errors or with horrible performance issues with entity framework. 

Is there a way I can offset those issues ? 

Also does this mean that I have to use my ORM models as domain models ? how would this work if my domain Objective class was different from the ORM objective class ?

Comment: @Pratik Missing `ToList()` can be easily noticed during code review (together with many other bugs and code smells - it's really worth the time). EF code-first doesn't have many extra requirements on the classes it uses - usually you can use domain model as ORM model (not the other way around - domain goes first). Adding another layer of DTOs only complicates things. And even if you have a separate persistence model, you will just end up with 2 projections in queries.